# Decaying way to compute sample mean

Tags: probability-theory

Let $x$ be some random variable, and consider $s_{n+1} = ax_n + (1- a)s_n$, with $s_0 = 0$ and $x_n$ being iid samples drawn for distribution of $x$. Is it true that this sequence converge to a mean of $x$ (in probability/a.s./mean) under some suitable conditions? I saw this procedure being applied in [TD learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_difference_learning) (see e.g. the algorithm equation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-Action-Reward-State-Action), and I have some doubts about its convergence properties.

Comment: What is TD learning?

Comment: Ok, I looked this up a bit on wikipedia, and I saw something like this regarding the reinforcement process, where we are taking a sequence of prediction errors...

Answer (score 3):

I find this doubtful, since we are effectively giving each subsequent observation ($x_n$) a higher weight than the previous one...not a recipe for convergence when the $x_i$ are random.

In general:
$$s_n = \sum_{i=1}^n a(a-1)^{n-i}x_i$$

Thus, if $a \in (0,1)$

$$\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} s_n = \lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n a(a-1)^{n-i}x_i$$

However, for each $n$, all terms except $i=n$ are being multiplied by increasing powers of a number in $(0,1)$, which means that each of these terms approaches $0$.

This would imply that:

$$\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} s_n \propto \lim \limits_{n\to\infty} x_n$$

Since the other terms in the sum converge to $0$. However, this last term does not converge unless $x_n = \mathrm{constant}$ *surely*.

Now, if $a=1$, then we get the same result, since all intermediate terms *are* equal to zero, not even in the limit. Finally, if $a=0$ then the sum remains at $0$, which is useless.

So, I'm not sure how this is used to get a mean when it seems just as easy to compute the running mean the old-fashioned way...

Comment: "This would imply that: $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} s_n = \lim \limits_{n\to\infty} ax_n$" Actually, this would imply that $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} s_n = \lim \limits_{n\to\infty} x_n$ (but anyway if $(x_n)$ is i.i.d. the limit on the RHS does not exist hence the limit on the LHS does not exist either).

Comment: @Did I don't see why the $a$ drops out...but yes, I pointed out that the RHS doesn't exist, so I don't think it converges.

Comment: @Did...nm...sum has a known form...

Comment: I think an easier check is to see that variance of $s_n$ has a positive limit in the end, whereas if $a_n = \frac1n$ as in usual sample mean, then variance converges to zero.

Comment: @Ilya that's how I concluded that RHS doesn't converge....unless $x_n$ is constant (surely), then this limit does not exist.